# Why is My Recent Find Usages box always blank inside IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am not sure why, but this box is always blank.  Do I need to enable something inside IntelliJ settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-recent-find-usages.html) feature:

[image: menu]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/images/findUsagesRecent.png))</sub>

As far as I can tell it works just fine with no special options enabled.

Pick any class/field/method and choose: `Search` -> `Find Usages` and confirm. When the search is done I can go to `Search` -> `Recent Find Usages` and the last find is there in the submenu. Maybe you should consult Jetbrains support?

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 10.5 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Correct, what if you just do a regular 'search' though, not using 'find usages'?